# Looping through a List<Map<Integer, Map<Long, Integer>>> in Java

Tags: java, list, loops, data-structures, hashmap

As my title suggests, I'm struggling with looping through the data structure given.

I have a List of Maps which contain an Integer key and a Map value which contains a Long and an Integer.

How can I loop through the list, then map, then map to be able to access all of the required fields?

Thanks.

EDIT:
In response to the comments, the looping through the list I'm fine with.
So step one is to loop through the list, so I'm then left with:

```
for (Map<Integer, Map<Long, Integer>> periodScores : request.getPeriodScoreMap()) {
...
}
```

It's what goes in there that confuses me.

Currently I have:

```
for (Map<Integer, Map<Long, Integer>> periodScores : request.getPeriodScoreMap()) {
        while (periodScores.entrySet().iterator().hasNext()) {
            Map<Integer, Map<Long, Integer>> opponentScores =
                    (Map<Integer, Map<Long, Integer>>) periodScores.entrySet().iterator().next();
        }
    }
```

And I'm struggling to get into that final Map of

Comment: Do you know how to iterate the elements of `List`? Do you know how to iterate the `entrySet` of a `Map`?

Comment: What have you tried so far? Show us some code and we might be able to explain what you do not understand.

Comment: here is tip : you need three loops

Comment: What java version you are using ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

its just matter of being careful and being able to differentiate between `map` and `list` iterations

here is just an example:

```
for ( Map<Integer, Map<Long, Integer>> level1 : list){
   for(Map.Entry<Integer,Map<Long, Integer>> level2 : level1.entrySet() ){
      for(Map.Entry<Long,Integer> level3 : level2.getValue().entryList(){ 
      }
   }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this ;)

```
 List<Map<Integer, Map<Long, Integer>>> myList = new LinkedList<>();
    for(Map<Integer,Map<Long,Integer>> myListMap: myList){
        for(Entry<Integer, Map<Long,Integer> myListMapEntry : myListMap.entrySet()){
             Integer myListMapEntryInt = myListMapEntry.getKey();
             for(Entry<Long, Integer> myListMapEntryValue : myListMapEntry.getValue()){
                    Long myListMapEntryValueLong = myListMapEntryValue.getKey();
                    Integer myListMapEntryValueInteger = myListMapEntryValue.getValue();
             }
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

If the list of Maps is : List>> list;
Then you can access each Integer in the innermost map as follows:

```
 for(Map<Integer,Map<Long,Integer>> outerMap : list){
        for(Integer innerMapKeys : outerMap.keySet()){
            Map<Long,Integer> innerMap = outerMap.get(innerMapKeys);
            for(Long key:innerMap.keySet()){
                System.out.println(innerMap.get(key)); 
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: _@user403348255 next time use `{  }` in the answer box to format the code & +1 for ya :D

Comment: I am new to stack overflow; thanks for the info, will remember this pointer next time onward.